# Reducing the distortion of transmitted light through a prismatic array

Tags: optics

I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce the distortion of light transmitted through a prismatic array (*without touching the surface of the prisms*).

[image]

The obvious thing to try is a corresponding prism array:

[image]

Although this might reduce some of the distortion, it is far from perfect. Is there something better? An array of concave lenses?

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.  As your drawing shows, even for monochromatic light, the exit angle is a function of both entrance angle and location (which side of each "tooth" the light enters).

Your term "distortion" is not well-defined here.  For one example,  a perfectly flat plate placed in a converging cone of light will cause the final spot to be astigmatic.  If you can give more details about your entire optic system and what you're trying to do,  we can suggest an approach.

Comment: I have posted the intended optics system as another [question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123872/one-way-window-using-circular-polariser-and-prismatic-array)